How to get list of JBOSS EJB threads through Java Program
I have very little knowledge in EJB & JBOSS. Our application is running in JBOSS EAP 7.1.4 and it launched few EJB threads (names starting with tSA). We can see those threads in Jboss Jconsole as shown in the picture.
Now I want to get these thread ids through a Java program. How can I connect to my Jboss eap and get the EJB threads that are running currently ?
Please help me on this.
Regards,
Manohar Amkem

This question is similar to: Get a list of all threads currently running in Java. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I would use a tool like 'jconsole' or 'jvisualvm' to browse the JBoss instance via JMX.  Find what you want, then use some JMX java code once you know the JMX location.
